# Traversing and adding elements to a Data.Tree using Lenses in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, haskell-lens, lenses

I'm starting to use lenses and until now I've been unable to use them in a concrete part of a codebase I'm writing. My objective is to update a rose tree structure such as the one in `Data.Tree` by adding a new node inside one of the existing ones. To do so I thought that it would make sense to identify each node with a unique id, so it would look like that:

```
type MyTree = Tree Id
type Path = [Id]

addToTree :: MyTree -> MyTree -> Path -> MyTree
addToTree originalTree newNode path = undefined
```

The function `addToTree` would have to traverse the `originalTree` by following the path of ids and add the `newNode` at that level, returning the whole updated tree. I haven't had problems to make a getter for that but I'm not being able to find an appropriate lens to perform the operation with.

That's what I've got until now:

```
import           Control.Lens
import           Data.Tree
import           Data.Tree.Lens

addToTree :: MyTree -> Path -> MyTree -> MyTree
addToTree tree path branch = tree & (traversalPath path) . branches %~ (branch:)

traversalPath :: (Foldable t, Applicative f, Contravariant f) => t Id -> (MyTree -> f MyTree) -> MyTree -> f MyTree
traversalPath = foldl (\acc id-> acc . childTraversal id) id

childTraversal :: (Indexable Int p, Applicative f) => Id -> p MyTree (f MyTree) -> MyTree -> f MyTree
childTraversal id = branches . traversed . withId id

withId :: (Choice p, Applicative f) => Id -> Optic' p f MyTree MyTree
withId id = filtered (\x -> rootLabel x == id)
```

But it fails to compile with:

> ```
> • No instance for (Contravariant Identity)
>     arising from a use of ‘traversalPath’
> • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘(traversalPath path)’
>   In the first argument of ‘(%~)’, namely
>     ‘(traversalPath path) . branches’
>   In the second argument of ‘(&)’, namely
>     ‘(traversalPath path) . branches %~ (branch :)’
> ```

Thanks!

Comment: Minor clarification: is the root of the `originalTree` part of the `path`?

Comment: I didn't include it in the path during my pseudoimplementation but it would make sense for it to be there. I would say yes.

Comment: `Contravariant` is for getting, you want to set, and you never use `cmap`. Remove the `Contravariant` constraint from `traversalPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specially elegant, but should do the trick:

```
import Control.Lens
import Data.Monoid (Endo(..)) -- A tidier idiom for 'foldr (.) id'.
import Data.List.NonEmpty (NonEmpty(..)) -- You don't want an empty path.
import qualified Data.List.NonEmpty as N
import Data.Tree
import Data.Tree.Lens -- That's where I got 'branches' from.

addToTree :: Eq a => NonEmpty a -> Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
addToTree path newNode oldTree = head $ over pathForests (newNode :) [oldTree]
    where
    pathForests = appEndo $ foldMap (Endo . goDown) path 
    goDown x = traverse . filtered ((x ==) . rootLabel) . branches
```

(In particular, I never like using `head`, even in cases like this one in which it can't possibly fail. Feel free to replace it with your favourite circumlocution.)

Demo:

```
GHCi> addToTree (1 :| []) (Node 2 []) (Node 1 [])
Node {rootLabel = 1, subForest = [Node {rootLabel = 2, subForest = []}]}
GHCi> addToTree (4 :| []) (Node 2 []) (Node 1 [])
Node {rootLabel = 1, subForest = []}
GHCi> addToTree (1 :| [5]) (Node 2 []) (Node 1 [Node 5 [], Node 6 []])
Node {rootLabel = 1, subForest = [Node {rootLabel = 5, subForest = [Node {rootLabel = 2, subForest = []}]},Node {rootLabel = 6, subForest = []}]}
GHCi> addToTree (1 :| [7]) (Node 2 []) (Node 1 [Node 5 [], Node 6 []])
Node {rootLabel = 1, subForest = [Node {rootLabel = 5, subForest = []},Node {rootLabel = 6, subForest = []}]}
GHCi> addToTree (1 :| [5,3]) (Node 2 []) (Node 1 [Node 5 [], Node 6 []])
Node {rootLabel = 1, subForest = [Node {rootLabel = 5, subForest = []},Node {rootLabel = 6, subForest = []}]}
```

Do note that we are dealing with traversals, and not with lenses -- there is no guarantee or expectation that the target of the path exists or is unique.

Here is a more stylised variant, without `head` and using [`alaf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Wrapped.html#v:alaf) to handle the `Endo` wrapping.

```
addToTree :: Eq a => NonEmpty a -> Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
addToTree (desiredRoot :| path) newNode oldTree@(Node x ts)
    | x == desiredRoot = Node x (over pathForests (newNode :) ts)
    | otherwise = oldTree
    where
    pathForests = alaf Endo foldMap goDown path 
    goDown x = traverse . filtered ((x ==) . rootLabel) . branches
```